# How to synchronize UI and access objects from another thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, thread-safety

I'm quite new to parallel programming and threads. I want to calculate and add series to a chart, which unfortunately is a quite time-consuming task. So I'd like to show a loading screen in the meantime:

```
(.NET 4.0, WPF for UI)

ShowLoadingScreen(true);
CalculateAndUpdateChart(chartControl, settings);
ShowLoadingScreen(false);
...
private void ShowLoadingScreen(bool show) { loadingScreen.IsBusy = show; }
private void CalculateAndUpdateChart(ChartControl chart, ProductSettings settings)
{
    chart.SomeSettings = ...
    foreach(var item in settings.Items)
    {
        chart.Series.Points.Add(CalculateItem(item));
        ...
    }
}
```

But of course that doesn't work. So I guess I need to update the Chart control in another thread.

```
ShowLoadingScreen(true);
Tash.Factory.StartNew(()=>{CalculateAndUpdateChart(chartControl, settings)});
ShowLoadingScreen(false);
```

However, now I get different errors, most of how I cannot access chartControl and settings from another thread.

How can I access and change UI form another thread and how to pass objects created in one thread to another? Can you please give an analogous example of what I'm trying to do?

Comment: If you want to show the chart "building up", then Invoke within `CalculateAndUpdateChart` (as is); otherwise, if you want an all-at-once, I recommend running a task to `CalculateItem` for all items _then_ once you have all items calculated, Invoke to update the chart.

Comment: have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the non-UI thread to update a control on the UI thread, you must do:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(...);  OR
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...);
```

Start here:
[Build More Responsive Apps With The Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx)
and a little here: [Beginners Guide to Threading in .NET: Part 5 of n](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/ThreadingDotNet5.aspx)
and a small example: [Task Parallel Library: 1 of n](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/TPL1.aspx#wpf)

Comment: Good links. The BackgroundWorker example in the first article is really useful. I probably use this 80% of the time when I know I want to offload some processing to another thread but I don't care to manage the thread manually. I launch a "busy, please wait" screen, run the BackgroundWorker, and when the task is done, the BackgroundWorker raises an event in the UI thread that I can grab to update my controls and clear the busy screen.

Comment: @Kendrick: I usually do the same thing.  Although, when I have more time, I'd really like to dig into the TPL.  (BackgroundWorker is just still so dependable.  It just _works_.)

Answer (score 0):

you must do maybe this one

**EDIT/Update**

this works fine for me, but de gui thread is still blocked for the time of computing

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace TPLSpielwiese
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow() {
      this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
      TaskScheduler taskUI = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
      Task.Factory
        .StartNew(() =>
                    {
                      this.ShowLoadingScreen(true);
                    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, taskUI)
        .ContinueWith((t) =>
                        {
                          //CalculateAndUpdateChart(chartControl, settings);
                          Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, taskUI)
        .ContinueWith((t) =>
                        {
                          this.ShowLoadingScreen(false);
                        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, taskUI);
    }

    private Window loadScreen;

    private void ShowLoadingScreen(bool showLoadingScreen) {
      if (showLoadingScreen) {
        this.loadScreen = new Window() {Owner = this, WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner, Width = 100, Height = 100};
        this.loadScreen.Show();
      } else {
        this.loadScreen.Close();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work (you have also some syntax errors but I fixed those).